# Pass timezone name to Time.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

Can i somehow pass time zone name or abbreviation to Time.new.
I have all working with offset but i need timezone such as PST, GMT etc etc.

Kindly see my simple code below.

Following is working already

```
Time.new(year, month, day, hr, min, sec, utc_offset)
```

I want something like following to work.

```
Time.new(year, month, day, hr, min, sec, timezone_name/abbreviation)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Careful - time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous.  For example, there are 5 different interpretations of CST.  Is it "Central Standard Time", "China Standard Time", etc...  See [the list on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) for more examples.

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for the very useful comment. but i am only using us_zones. But yes you are right. I think i should store full timezone name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one

```
Time.use_zone('Dublin') { 
  # Time.now....
}
```

Example:

```
Time.use_zone('St. Petersburg') { DateTime.current }
```

> Thu, 29 Oct 2015 17:24:40 +0300

```
Time.use_zone('Berlin') { DateTime.current }
```

> Thu, 29 Oct 2015 15:24:59 +0100

For some more information have a look at the api (http://apidock.com/rails/Time/use_zone/class)

update:
you can extract all Time Information into an array:

```
Time.now.to_a
```

> [20, 42, 9, 30, 10, 2015, 5, 303, false, "CET"]

Comment: I basically want to store TimeZone . Something like Thu, 29 Oct 2015 15:24:59 +0100 PST

Comment: this fails in following scenario
2.2.2 :074 > Time.now.in_time_zone("Indiana (East)").to_a
 => [38, 34, 12, 30, 10, 2015, 5, 303, true, "EDT"] 
2.2.2 :075 > Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").to_a
 => [57, 34, 12, 30, 10, 2015, 5, 303, true, "EDT"]